# How to use `which` on an aliased command?

Tags: shell, zsh, alias, which

Like most users, I have a bunch of aliases set up to give a default set of flags for frequently used programs. For instance,

```
alias vim='vim -X'
alias grep='grep -E'
alias ls='ls -G'
```

The problem is that if I want to use `which` to see where my `vim`/`grep`/`ls`/etc is coming from, the alias gets in the way:

```
$ which vim
vim: aliased to vim -X
```

This is useful output, but not what I'm looking for in this case; I know `vim` is aliased to `vim -X` but I want to know where *that* `vim` is coming from.

Short of temporarily un-defining the alias just so I can use `which` on it, is there an easy way to have `which` 'unwrap' the alias and run itself on that?

**Edit:** It seems that `which` is a shell-builtin with different behaviors across different shells. In Bash, SiegeX's suggestion of the `--skip-alias` flag works; however, I'm on Zsh. Does something similar exist there?

Comment: in zsh, if you want to know *where that `vim` is coming from*, you'd use `where vim`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

`which` is actually a bad way to do things like this, as it makes guesses about your environment based on `$SHELL` and the startup files (it thinks) that shell uses; not only does it sometimes guess wrong, but you can't generally tell it to behave differently.  (`which` on my Ubuntu 10.10 doesn't understand `--skip-alias` as mentioned by @SiegeX, for example.)  `type` uses the current shell environment instead of poking at your config files, and can be told to ignore parts of that environment, so it shows you what will actually happen instead of what would happen in a reconstruction of your default shell.

In this case, `type -P` will bypass any aliases or functions:

```
$ type -P vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

You can also ask it to peel off *all* the layers, one at a time, and show you what it would find:

```
$ type -a vim
vim is aliased to `vim -X'
vim is /usr/bin/vim
```

(Expanding on this from the comments:)

The problem with `which` is that it's usually an external program instead of a shell built-in, which means it can't see your aliases or functions and has to try to reconstruct them from the shell's startup/config files.  (If it's a shell built-in, as it is in `zsh` but apparently not `bash`, it is more likely to use the shell's environment and do the right thing.)

`type` is a POSIX-compliant command which is required to behave as if it were a built-in (that is, it must use the environment of the shell it's invoked from including local aliases and functions), so it usually *is* a built-in.

It isn't generally found in `csh`/`tcsh`, although in most modern versions of those `which` is a shell builtin and does the right thing; sometimes the built-in is `what` instead, and sometimes there's no good way to see the current shell's environment from `csh`/`tcsh` at all.

Comment: Thanks! This is something very useful to add to my bag of tricks. I especially like that `type -a` seems to return *all* instances on your `$PATH`, not just the first one. I think I'll alias `which` to `type` :)

Comment: `type` appears to be a bash builtin. Does this work on other shells?

Comment: `type` is part of POSIX, and derived from the original System V shell.  It won't work on `csh`/`tcsh`; some versions of those have a `what` builtin, others may have a built-in version of `which` that behaves like `type` instead of like the standalone `which` (the stand-alone-ness is why it has to guess, btw; built-in versions are more likely to do the right thing, as it has to be built in to see what aliases and functions you have).

Comment: @ geekosaur: Thanks. If `type` is part of the POSIX standard then that is the way to go. To answer my question, type works on zsh too (on Debian). Why don't the distributions get rid of `what` and `which` if they aren't standardized and don't have extra functionality?

Comment: Don't `csh/tcsh` follow the POSIX standard?

Comment: Nope, not even remotely.

Comment: @geekosaur: Ok, thanks. Where is a good place to look for the type documentation on a Linux system?

Comment: @Faheem: For the same reason `csh`/`tcsh` still exist:  they have a long history and there's still a lot of stuff that uses them. (`which` is actually much older than `type`.) See for example the OpenOffice build system.

Comment: @Faheem: re documentation, I'd start with `info bash 'Bash builtins'` on Linux, although you can also get it form the `zsh` reference manual. More officially, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/type.html (which I note doesn't actually spec `-P` or `-a`, or even `-p` which was the original form of `-P`, but does require that it use the current shell environment).

Comment: @geekosaur: Thanks. That's informative. The link you give, which I assume is the POSIX standard, has little detail, and if it doesn't have the options discussed here, does that mean they are not part of the standard? Perhaps Linux should move towards depreciating `which` etc.

Comment: Incredibly, the bash info manual is not available in Debian. How appalling. See [Debian bug report 427804](http://bugs.debian.org/427804).

Comment: @Faheem: it's complex. `type` originates from the System V shell, and the behavior I'm describing actually comes from the old SVID standard (POSIX is largely a subset of the SVID). POSIX hasn't specced those, but most shells implement the SVID behavior because it's more useful. (As to why, POSIX specs a subset which is usable on more than just Unix. For example, you can do POSIX `type` on a POSIX shell running on OpenVMS, but it's not obvious how `-P` should deal with commands that are logical names or other things that are neither disk files nor covered in POSIX.)

Comment: @Faheem: Yeh, I'm seriously considering a cron job to look for installed packages with uninstalled `-doc` packages and install them. Annoying. Should probably be an `apt-get` configuration option to automatically install docs.

Comment: @geekosaur: In this case, it wouldn't do any good. It's not even in non-free.:-( Missing for no reason, apparently.

Comment: OP says he's using `zsh`, so it should be `type -p vim` rather than `type -P vim`.

Comment: *As to why, POSIX specs a subset which is usable on more than just Unix.* This subset is sometimes so narrow it actually doesn't specify any useful behavior so it's basically useless. This is such a case.

Comment: `type -p` behaves differently between zsh and bash. `type -P` does not exist in zsh at all.

Comment: From this answer I had the idea to alias `which` to `type -a` because `which` is so ingrained in my head. Maybe somebody else reading this would also find that useful.

Comment: At present day, debian `which` doesn't resolve aliases. It does a simple and basic task: *find first executable on the PATH that match given name*.  So, it doesn't have (nor need) the `--skip-alias` option and it is now an useful utility.

Comment: In `zsh`, both `which` and `type` call `whence`, so there are only output format and verbosity differences.

Comment: None of these suggestions work on zhs on mac :( I have an alias I can't locate and thus can't remove :((

Answer (score 19):

In `bash`:

```
type -P vim
```

In `zsh`:

```
type -p vim
```

In both:

```
/usr/bin/which vim
```

Or:

```
( unalias vim; type vim )
```

Comment: Last one is cool. We can have an alias to do this. :)

Comment: In bash on redhat I have to use type -P, and not which, if i want the correct answer.  No aliases or functions are concerned.

Comment: Dr Eval, which "which"? Which Red Hat?

Comment: @Mikel RH7.4. GNU which v2.20.

Comment: ++ /usr/bin/which is what I really wanted. Helped me realize `which` isn't even what I thought it was on `zsh`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In zsh `which` is a builtin as this command reports:

```
$ whence -w which
which: builtin
```

To execute the *external command* (in any shell) `which`,
use the *Full Path*:

```
$ /bin/which ls; echo $?
/bin/ls
0
```

thus the command `ls` was found (an exit value of 0), and is located at `/bin/ls`.

Inside `zsh`; a way (beside the one above) to search for *external commands* is:

```
$ whence -p ls
/bin/ls
```

However, that will not resolve nested aliases like:

```
$ alias dire='ls -l'
```

The command will report that no `dire` command was found.

```
$ whence -p dire; echo $?
1
```

For resolving nested aliases (manually) see [`Resolve nested aliases to their source commands`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146699/resolve-nested-aliases-to-their-source-commands)

Answer (score 3):

Mine defined as such

```
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is `command which vim`, which works the same way in both `zsh` and `bash`

E.g. on my mac:

```
LOLcalhost :: ~ % command which grep
/usr/local/bin/grep
```

Comment: Ah fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
which --skip-alias vim
```

Comment: Interesting! This works on Bash, but not on Zsh (I really didn't think this was going to be shell-dependent). This made me realize that `which` is actually a shell built-in and not a regular Unix utility as I had assumed. So I should edit my question and specify Zsh. Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Comment: `which` is not a builtin, at least not on Debian. It is a shell script, and part of debianutils, so works on zsh. However, `--skip-alias` is not an option the `which` on Debian. Are there different varieties of `which` floating around? This does not apppear to be a standardized command.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: It is a zsh builtin.  See `man zshbuiltins`.  *which [ -wpams ] name ...           Equivalent to whence -c.*

Comment: Yeah on Xubuntu's `bash`, it is not a built-in and doesn't have the `--skip-alias` option.

Comment: On CentOS (and RHEL?) 6, it's an executable `/usr/bin/which` plus an alias in `/etc/profile.d` that lets it handle aliases but `--skip-alias` works. As a result `which which` shows the alias, but `command which which` shows the executable!

Answer (score 1):

Both `type` and `which` behave differently according to your shell type.

In bash, `which` is a command exists in `PATH`. It searches the command you provide in `PATH`. Bash builtin `type -P` (P for `PATH`) behaves exactly like `which`.

In ZSH, both `which` and `type` are builtins, and partial functions of builtin `whence`. `which -p` is what you want. It forces a path search. (`-P` option is not available for `type` ZSH.)

> whence [ -vcwfpamsS ] [ -x num ] name ...
>
> -p
>
> Do  a  path  search  for name even if it is an alias, reserved word, shell function or builtin.

More from ZSH manual.

> which [ -wpamsS ] [ -x num ] name ...
>
> Equivalent to whence -c.

To skip `builtin` `which` and force use command `which` from `PATH` in ZSH:

```bsh
alias which="command which"
```