# How do I get which to show aliases?

Tags: shell, alias, which

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use `which` on an aliased command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command)

I'm used to working on systems where `which` would list aliases, so e.g. if I have an alias like this:

```
alias foo=/path/to/executable
```

Then I get meaningful output from `which foo`. (From memory it's something like `alias: /path/to/executable`).

On my Macbook Pro (Snow Leopard) this doesn't work. I seem to recall it's non-standard and needs an alias of its own (on `which`) to work, but I've forgotten the details. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

(I'm a bash man if that makes any difference to your answer.)

Answer (score 12):

I would use `type` instead of `which`, because `which` is unreliable (as you noticed; unless it's a shell builtin, it has to guess at your environment).

Comment: Thanks, hadn't come across `type` before. There's a lot of muscle memory for me to overcome in order to wean off `which` though. :)

Comment: `alias which type`?

Comment: I like `alias where='type -a'`

Comment: I do the same as glenn, but mine is: alias witch='type -a', and just to play it safe for forgetful me: alias which=witch