# Why would vim return non-zero exit code if I exit immediately after opening?

Tags: vim, osx

I'm running into a bit of a strange problem w/ `vim` on Snow Leopard: I get a non-zero exit code from simply running `vim` and then quitting.

```
$ vim
# exit immediately using :q
$ echo $?
1
```

However, if I use the full path to `vim`, I don't see this behavior

```
$ /usr/bin/vim
# exit immediately using :q
$ echo $?
0
```

At first I thought `vim` was coming from somewhere earlier in my path, but:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

So I'm at a loss. What could be causing this?

UPDATE: This problem has magically resolved itself, which makes me highly suspicious. My current best theory is that I had a problem with my `.vimrc` or a plugin that I fixed accidentally while tweaking my setup in some other way. If I can track down exactly what I did to fix it, I will definitely update with that info. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I fixed it in a Makefile by adding `-u NONE`, which tells vim to load no config file at all. Might help in some situations.

Answer (score 14):

Do you have `filetype off` in your vimrc? Try replacing it with:

```
filetype on
filetype off
```

I had this problem using Tim Pope's Pathogen on OS X. [This article](http://call%20pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles%28%29) helped me solve the issue. If you are using Pathogen...

```
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
```

...do this instead:

```
filetype on
filetype off
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
call pathogen#helptags()
filetype plugin indent on
```

http://andrewho.co.uk/weblog/vim-pathogen-with-mutt-and-git

Comment: This is a good point. I had already fixed this *particular* issue, but it is what led me to suspect that I accidentally fixed an error somewhere else in my `.vimrc`.

Comment: This fixed an identical issue for me except with Vundle rather than Pathogen.

Comment: Just like to add another +1, this is an old fix, but it just worked for me fixing this problem using Vundle on an OSX system. Just threw `filetype on` above the existing `filetype off`.

Answer (score 8):

I can think of two possible explanations.

1. `vim` is actually an alias. Note that [`which` doesn't show aliases, you should use `type` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command) (unless you're running csh or tcsh).
2. Vim goes to look for some file in a path relative to its installation directory, which it determines from looking at `argv[0]` (the name of the executable as passed from the shell), and somehow fails to find that path if it's called through a relative path. That would be technically possible, but I don't think Vim actually does that.

Answer (score 7):

> I get a non-zero exit code from simply running vim and then quitting.

That doesn't happen here, with a similar system: Snow Leopard, and the stock version of Vim.

Try this command:

```
$ sudo dtruss vim +q
```

That will get you a list of all the syscalls Vim makes while it initializes and then immediately shuts down. (`dtruss` is equivalent to `strace` on Linux, if you've used that before.)

What you're looking for is a line close to the end that shows an error code, typically -1. Looking at the arguments to the system call should lead you to the problem. One high likelihood possibility is a missing file, which will probably show up on an `open()` call.

If Vim exits cleanly when run this way, you probably have a permission problem, which the `sudo` needed to allow `dtruss` to run is getting around. In that case, you can probably fix it by [repairing permissions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452).

Comment: Sorry - I'm on my work machine now and it doesn't have this behavior. I'll be sure to check it out once I'm on my home machine again, though.

Comment: If you can't figure it out, append the `dtruss` output to your question. (Or at least, the last 25 lines or so.) What is incomprehensible to you may lead another to the right answer.

Comment: @nlucaroni: Glad to hear it. For posterity, though, *which* of the two ideas in my answer fixed it? That is, did you have a permission problem that `sudo` "fixed", letting you know you needed to run Repair Permissions? Or was it rather that `dtruss` showed you a syscall error, and if so, which one and why was it failing?

Comment: syscall errors in opening files that weren't there. My co-worker had just taken someone elses zipp'd `.vim` directory and `.vimrc`, and things had full paths and missing files from unused plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I had hit this return codes problem. I traced it back to a silently executing `loadview` command in my vimrc which provides persistent views:

```
" Persistent views
if has("mksession")
    set viewdir=$HOME/.vimviews
    if has("unix")
        silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vimviews'
    endif
    au BufWinLeave * silent! mkview "make vim save view (state) (folds, cursor, etc)
    au BufWinEnter * silent! loadview "make vim load view (state) (folds, cursor, etc)
endif
```

When entering a buffer without a filename, the `silent! loadview` would execute, hiding the error

> E32: No file name

which had also caused the return code to be set to one.