# On OSX, vi seems to return 1 unexpectedly despite no error

Tags: osx, vi

So, on stock Mac OSX Yosemite, if I run `vi /tmp/foo` and then type in some text, and finally do `:Wq` (a common typo I make) and then `:wq`. Everything will appear to be fine, but for some reason the exit code will be 1. If I repeat the same thing, but don't do `:Wq` then it returns 0.

This is maddening for git commit where I'll type in a commit message, make this mistake and suddenly lose my commit message because git things vi didn't write the file

How can I fix this behavior to not happen anymore and always return 0 unless there is a real error with writing the file?

Comment: Possibly related... http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14497/why-would-vim-return-non-zero-exit-code-if-i-exit-immediately-after-opening

Answer (score 2):

This is done intentionally in vim:

- the **`":wq"`** command calls, [`ex_exit`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/ex_docmd.c#L7585),
- which calls [`getout`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/ex_docmd.c#L7626) with a nominal exit-code **`0`**,
- in [`getout`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/main.c#L1404), it checks for an error in ex-mode, commenting

```
    /* When running in Ex mode an error causes us to exit with a non-zero exit
     * code.  POSIX requires this, although it's not 100% clear from the
     * standard. */
    if (exmode_active)
        exitval += ex_exitval;
```

- the `ex_exitval` variable is set by the error-message in [`emsg`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/message.c#L529):

```
    called_emsg = TRUE;
    if (emsg_silent == 0)
        ex_exitval = 1;
```

- and `ex_exitval` is *never* cleared.

So "any" error message in ex-mode (the **`:`** commands) will produce this result.  A quick check shows that the vi-mode `ZZ` also is affected by ex-mode error-messages.