# Output of which command used for input to cd

Tags: bash, cd-command, which

I would like to take the output of a which command, and cd to the parent directory. For example, say I have the following:

```
which someprogram
```

With output:

```
/home/me/somedirectory/someprogram
```

And I would like to cd to the directory that someprogram lives in:

```
cd /home/me/somedirectory
```

I'd like to accomplish this in one line.
What is the most elegant, tricky, short way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `dirname`:

```
cd "`dirname $(which program)`"
```

Comment: +1 but use `$()` instead of backticks: `cd $(dirname $(which program))`

Comment: @glennjackman It works fine with one pair of backticks (as shown in the answer, or the other way around with the $() on the outside and the backticks on the inside). It just wouldn't work with an inner pair of backticks nested inside a separate outer pair of backticks.

Comment: @EliahKagan I think @glennjackman's point was not that backticks don't work, but that they should be gradually phased out in favor of `$()` due to the [many advantages](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) of `$()` over backticks.

Answer (score 5):

In bash, I recommend `type -p` over `which`. [`which` is an external command and it's tricky at times](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command). You can use `sed` to remove everything after the final `/`, or use the special-purpose `dirname` utility.

```
cd "$(dirname -- "$(type -p program)")"
cd "$(type -p program | sed 's:[^/]*$::')"
```

On the command line, if you know that the directory doesn't contain any special characters (whitespace or `\[?*`), you can omit the quotes. You can also use backquotes instead of one of the `$(…)` (nesting backquotes is difficult, not worth it here).

```
cd `dirname $(type -p program)`
cd $(dirname `type -p program`)
cd `type -p program | sed 's:[^/]*$::'`
```

In zsh, there's a more compact syntax.

```
cd ${$(whence -p program):h}
cd ${$(echo =program):h}
cd ${${_+=program}:h}
```

(Yes, that last one is cryptic. It uses the `${VAR+TEXT}` syntax on the `_` variable, with the value being `=program` which is equivalent to `$(whence -p program)`.)