# My `which` command may be wrong (sometimes)?

Tags: bash, emacs, path, which

I've compiled the last emacs version from the source code (v24.2) because the version installed on my machine is (quite) old for me (v21.3). I've done the usual:

```
$configure --prefix=$HOME
make 
make install
```

Now I am testing emacs and realized that it still launches the previous version ... while my `$HOME/bin` path is supposed to override the system one (since it is prepended to $PATH in my `.bashrc` file).

My first thought was to see the `which` command output. And surprise, it gives the path to the new emacs. I can't understand where is the discrepancy here. In the same session here is the different outputs:

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 21.3.1

$ `which emacs` --version
GNU Emacs 24.2.1
```

I have no alias involving emacs. At all.

```
$ alias | grep emacs
$
```

Any idea what is going on please?

Comment: what does which emacs return?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The three possibilities that come to mind for me:

- An alias exists for `emacs` (which you've checked)
- A function exists for `emacs`
- The new `emacs` binary is not in your shell's PATH hashtable.

You can check if you have a function `emacs`:

```
bash-3.2$ declare -F | fgrep emacs
declare -f emacs
```

And remove it:

```
unset -f emacs
```

Your shell also has a PATH hashtable which contains a reference to each binary in your PATH. If you add a new binary with the same name as an existing one elsewhere in your PATH, the shell needs to be informed by updating the hashtable:

```
hash -r
```

---

Additional explanation:

`which` doesn't know about functions, as it is not a bash builtin:

```
bash-3.2$ emacs() { echo 'no emacs for you'; }
bash-3.2$ emacs
no emacs for you
bash-3.2$ which emacs
/usr/bin/emacs
bash-3.2$ `which emacs` --version | head -1
GNU Emacs 22.1.1
```

New binary hashtable behaviour is demonstrated by this script.

```
bash-3.2$ PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
bash-3.2$ cd $HOME/bin

bash-3.2$ cat nofile
cat: nofile: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ echo echo hi > cat
bash-3.2$ chmod +x cat
bash-3.2$ cat nofile
cat: nofile: No such file or directory

bash-3.2$ hash -r
bash-3.2$ cat nofile
hi
bash-3.2$ rm cat
bash-3.2$ cat nofile
bash: /Users/mrb/bin/cat: No such file or directory

bash-3.2$ hash -r
bash-3.2$ cat nofile
cat: nofile: No such file or directory
```

Although I didn't call it, `which cat` would always return the first `cat` in my PATH, because it doesn't use the shell's hashtable.

Comment: While there is good information here, it misses out on the `type` command.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue with a freshly compiled version of sqlite3 which made me nut (which actually did return the right path, but the shell didn't call the right sqlite3 cli). `hash -r` did fix my issue.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, [don't use which](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command):

- On some systems, it's an external command implemented as a csh script, which may read a configuration that changes the `PATH`.
- There's a builtin for that. Two, even: `type` and `command`. The POSIX way:

  ```
  command -v emacs       # machine-readable format
  type emacs             # human-only format
  ```

  In bash, you can also use `type -p emacs` to see just the path of an external command.

However, here, `which` is actually right. Bash keeps information about the location of a command in memory, so that it can execute the command faster the next time. You've installed a new `emacs` executable on your `PATH`, but bash still has the old location in its cache. Run `hash emacs` to look up `emacs` again, or `hash -r` to empty the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Did you logout and login to cause your updated `.bashrc` login file to be re-read?  If not, your current session's environment hasn't been updated.

Comment: If that were the case, `\`which emacs\` --version` would agree with `emacs --version`, because `which` inherits its PATH from the current shell.

Comment: @mrb : Point well taken.