# Find the location of /gnu

Tags: path, gnu

I'm working on my university server and trying to find the location of /gnu. I know that it is installed with the latest version as I get the correct version using:`g++ --version`

On using find `find gnu` it return no result. How can I find the path to gnu?

Comment: What operating system is this? Post the output of `uname -a`. If this is Linux, what distribution? (Try `lsb_release -d`). What makes you think there is a `/gnu` anywhere? Why are you looking for it: [what are you trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 2):

There normally isn't a command or file called `gnu`.

The name `gnu` refers to the [GNU Project](http://www.gnu.org/), and includes a number of distinct programs, including gcc, emacs, the Bash shell, the Coreutils suite (which includs commands like `rm`, `cp`, `mv`, and so forth), and a number of other things. The goal of the project is/was to create an entire operating system.

On *some* systems, GNU tools might be installed in a special directory, perhaps `/opt/gnu` or `/gnu`. On others, including most Linux-based (or "GNU/Linux") systems, the GNU tools make up a large part of the operating system.

There is no "current version" of GNU; each sub-project (gcc, coreutils, emacs, ...) has its own series of releases.

Incidentally, your question asks about the location of `/gnu`.  `/gnu`, if it exists, *is* a location. And `find gnu` is going to (attempt to) traverse the `gnu` directory *in your current directory*. I suggest you need to study the workings of Unix-like file systems.

Answer (score 0):

which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.

```
~> which g++
/usr/bin/g++
```

find - search for files in a directory hierarchy

`find /  | grep gnu` (for example)

Comment: Only use `which` in `csh` or `tcsh` shells (will also work in `zsh`). Use `type` in Bourne-like shells.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas why? `which` is `/usr/bin/which` on my system, so it works anywhere. At least as long as PATH is exported, which it normally is... (besides, you'd use `command -v`, which gives the same output as `which` would. )

Comment: @derobert, it's a bit of a FAQ here, see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10529/22565), [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47406/22565) and [here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/689/22565). `which` is a broken non-standard work around for shells that don't have an equivalent builtin. `command -v` is fine but less useful when commands are aliased or defined as functions.

Comment: `find /` is likely to take a *very* long time to run, especially if the system has network-mounted file systems; it's also going to give you a whole lot of error messages for directories you don't have permission to read or traverse.