# Why is using && 75 times faster than if...fi and how to make code clearer

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have the following working code:

```
largest_prime=1
for number_under_test in {1..100}
do
  is_prime=true
  factors=''
  for ((divider = 2; divider < number_under_test-1; divider++));
  do
    remainder=$(($number_under_test % $divider))
    [ $remainder == 0 ] && [ is_prime ] && is_prime=false && factors+=$divider' '
  done
  [ $is_prime == true ] && echo "${number_under_test} is prime!" || echo "${number_under_test} is NOT prime (factors= $factors)"  [ $is_prime == true ] && largest_prime=$number_under_test
done
printf "\nLargest Prime= $largest_prime\n"
```

This code runs quickly is 0.194 seconds.  However I found the `&& is_prime= false` a bit hard to read and it could look (to the untrained eye) as if it was being tested rather than being set which is what it does.
So I tried changed the `&&` into an `if...then` and this works - but is 75 times slower at 14.48 seconds.  It's most noticeable on the higher numbers.

```
largest_prime=1
for number_under_test in {1..100}
do
  is_prime=true
  factors=''
  for ((divider = 2; divider < number_under_test-1; divider++));
  do  
    remainder=$(($number_under_test % $divider))
    if ([ $remainder == 0 ] && [ $is_prime == true ]); then
      is_prime=false
      factors+=$divider' '
    fi  
  done
  [ $is_prime == true ] && echo "${number_under_test} is prime!" || echo "${number_under_test} is NOT prime (factors= $factors)"  [ $is_prime == true ] && largest_prime=$number_under_test
done  
printf "\nLargest Prime= $largest_prime\n"
```

Is there any was to have the clarity of the block without the slowness?

#### Update (1/4/2015 10:40am EST)

Great feedback!  I am now using the following.  Any other feedback ?

```
largest_prime=1
separator=' '
for number_under_test in {1..100}; {
  is_prime=true
  factors=''
  for ((divider = 2; divider < (number_under_test/2)+1; divider++)) {
    remainder=$(($number_under_test % $divider))
    if [ $remainder == 0 ]; then
      is_prime=false
      factors+=$divider' '
    fi
  } 
  if $is_prime; then
    printf "\n${number_under_test} IS prime\n\n"
    largest_prime=$number_under_test
  else
    printf "${number_under_test} is NOT prime, factors are: "
    printf "$factors\n"
  fi
}
printf "\nLargest Prime= $largest_prime\n"
```

Comment: On a sidenote, running your script prints that `Largest Prime= 100` on my computer.

Comment: Also on a sidenote, if you're interested in efficiency, one trivial way to improve this would be to only iterate up to `number_under_test/2` instead of up to `number_under_test-1`: No factor of a number n is greater than n/2, so you will still find all factors for non-prime numbers by doing this. (Also if you were only interested in *testing* for primeness, it would be sufficient to iterate up to sqrt(n), but Bash doesn't have a built-in function to compute square roots anyway.)

Comment: Matte, good point (+1).  The only change was that didn't work for the number 4 so I had to make it `(number_under_test/2)+1` to allow for that

Comment: In your updated version, the braces `{}` are not really needed after the `then` clause because the `then` already serves as a grouping operator (along with `elif`, `else`, or `fi`).  In fact, in some shells, you could write, for example, `for i in 1 2 3; { echo $i; }` with no `do` or `done`.

Comment: +1 Jonathan, I made those changes and updated the update

Comment: you should `unset IFS`. `if $is_prime` will fail unless `$is_prime` evals to a *word*. If it is split for any reason it will fail. You also have the problem of needing to generate your entire parameter set before you can do even a single calculation. It is very inefficient and the whole `{1..100}` block must reside in memory for the duration.

Comment: `if [ $remainder == 0 ]` -- this is an arithmetic test, so use an arithmetic expression: `if (( $remainder == 0 ))` -- or remove the temp variable altogether: `if (( $number_under_test % $divider == 0 ))`. You don't actually use the `$separator` variable anywhere

Comment: Don't use `printf` without a format specifier. If one of your variables happens to contain a `%`, you'll get an error.

Comment: @glennjackman - if the content of the variables is questionable then `(( $var ))` is definitely *not* a safe thing to do. Rather `(( var ))` should be preferred. But `((...))` is probably not a good way to go, anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv, why not a good way to go?

Comment: @glennjackman - just because it offers no advantage over `[ "$((...))" -ne 0 ]` or even `math() { return "$((!($*)))"; }` but is far less portable. You might as well use syntax that will work everywhere rather limiting the application of what you do if the practical difference amounts only to typing a few characters.

Comment: @glennjackman - actually, I think, in `bash` and `zsh` at least even `(( var ))` is still an unsafe thing to do. I think both of those shells will still wind up evaling the contents as a math statement rather than an integer regardless of whether you `$expand` it first or not. You could explicitly `typeset` it first, I suppose, to guard against that. But if you do so, then its contents are no longer questionable.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

That's because you're spawning a sub-shell every time:

```
if ([ $remainder == 0 ] && [ $is_prime == true ]); then
```

Just remove the parentheses

```
if [ $remainder == 0 ] && [ $is_prime == true ]; then
```

If you want to group commands, there's syntax to do that in the *current* shell:

```
if { [ $remainder == 0 ] && [ $is_prime == true ]; }; then
```

(the trailing semicolon is required, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping))

Note that `[ is_prime ]` is not the same as `[ $is_prime == true ]`: you could write that as simply `$is_prime` (with no brackets) which would invoke the bash built-in `true` or `false` command.
`[ is_prime ]` is a test with one argument, the string "is_prime" -- when `[` is given a single argument, the result is success if the argument is non-empty, and that literal string is always non-empty, hence always "true".

For readability, I would change the very long line

```
[ $is_prime == true ] && echo "${number_under_test} is prime!" || echo "${number_under_test} is NOT prime (factors= $factors)"  [ $is_prime == true ] && largest_prime=$number_under_test
```

to

```
if [ $is_prime == true ]; then
  echo "${number_under_test} is prime!"
else 
  echo "${number_under_test} is NOT prime (factors= $factors)"
  # removed extraneous [ $is_prime == true ] test that you probably
  # didn't notice off the edge of the screen
  largest_prime=$number_under_test
fi
```

Don't underestimate whitespace to improve clarity.

Comment: there is a Typo - `largest_prime=$number_under_test` should be in the then branch (the same error is in the original)

Comment: It's also worth noting that in bash, zsh, et al, `[` is invoking a program literally called `[`, whereas `[[` is implemented in the shell - hence it'll be faster. Try `time for ((i = 0; $i < 1000; i++)); do [ 1 ]; done` and compare to `[[`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts) for further info.

Comment: bash implements `[`, it's a builtin. From a shell prompt, type `type -a [` and `help [`

Comment: @glennjackman Wow; wasn't aware of that. I assumed it was still the case because `which [` still returns `/usr/bin/[`. I also just realised that I implied zsh was the same; for me that does tell me it's a builtin. But then... why is [[ faster?

Comment: `which` only looks at executable files in the PATH. Try `less /bin/which`. `type -a` is preferable for bash (IMO)

Comment: @glennjackman [`command -v`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) is another good `which` alternative; see also [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47406/5092).

Answer (score 9):

I think you're working way too hard on that function of yours. Consider:

```
unset num div lprime; set -- "$((lprime=(num=(div=1))))"
while [     "$((     num += ! ( div *= ( div <= num   ) ) ))" -eq \
            "$((     num *=   ( div += 1 )   <= 101   ))" ]    && {
      set   "$(( ! ( num %      div )         * div   ))"     "$@"
      shift "$(( !    $1 +    ( $1 ==  1 )    *  $#   ))"
}; do [ "$div" -gt "$num" ] && echo "$*"      
done
```

Shell arithmetic is pretty capable of evaluating integer conditions on its own. It rarely needs too many tests and/or outside assignments. This one `while` loop duplicates your nested loops fairly well:

It doesn't print as much, of course, I didn't write all that much, but, for example setting the ceiling to 16 rather than 101 as is written above and...

```
2
3
4 2
5
6 3 2
7
8 4 2
9 3
10 5 2
11
12 6 4 3 2
13
14 7 2
15 5 3
```

It's definitely doing the work.  And it requires very little else to approximate your output:

```
...
do [ "$div" -eq "$num" ] && shift &&
   printf "$num ${1+!}= prime.${1+\t%s\t%s}\n" \
          "factors= $*"                        \
          "lprime=$(( lprime = $# ? lprime : num ))"
done
```

Just doing that rather than the `echo` and...

```
1 = prime.
2 = prime.
3 = prime.
4 != prime.     factors= 2      lprime=3
5 = prime.
6 != prime.     factors= 3 2    lprime=5
7 = prime.
8 != prime.     factors= 4 2    lprime=7
9 != prime.     factors= 3      lprime=7
10 != prime.    factors= 5 2    lprime=7
11 = prime.
12 != prime.    factors= 6 4 3 2        lprime=11
13 = prime.
14 != prime.    factors= 7 2    lprime=13
15 != prime.    factors= 5 3    lprime=13
```

This works in `busybox`. It is very portable, fast, and easy to use.

Your subshell issue is going to occur in most shells, but it is, by *far*, most acute in a `bash` shell. I alternated between doing

```
( [ "$div" -gt "$num" ] ) && ...
```

...and the way I wrote it above in several shells for a ceiling of 101 and `dash` did it without the subshell in .017 seconds and with the subshell in 1.8 seconds. `busybox` .149 and 2, zsh .149 and 4, `bash` .35 and 6, and `ksh93` in .149 and .160. `ksh93` does not fork for subshells as the other shells must. So maybe the problem is not so much the subshell as it is the *shell*.

Comment: What's the advantage of `[ "$((...))" -eq "$((...))" ]` over `(( (...) == (...) ))`? Is the latter less portable?

Comment: @ruakh - portability, speed, reliability. `[ "$((...))" -eq "$((...)) ]` works in shells that *don't* take 15 seconds to run the program, and the other doesn't. If the advantage of one over another is questionable at all, then that can only give the edge to the former, which means there is *never* a good reason to use `(( (...) == (...) ))`.

Comment: Sorry, but your reply seems to assume that I already have a detailed knowledge of shell support for `(( ... ))`. I'm flattered, but I *do* not have that detailed knowledge. (Remember, I'm the one who just asked if `(( ... ))` is less portable.) So I really can't make sense of your reply. :-/   Could you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: @ruakh - I'm sorry... I didn't see that you were asking if it was more portable, just how it was advantageous - which is why I replied about portability. Anyway, the `"$((...))"` is [POSIX-specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) and the other is a shell extension. POSIX shells are pretty capable. Even `dash` and `posh` will correctly handle branch tests like `"$((if_true ? (var=10) : (var=5) ))"` and always assign `$var` correctly. `busybox` breaks there - it always evals both sides regardless of `$if_true`'s value.

Comment: @ruakh - oh man. I must be a little off today... it says right there... *is the latter less portable*? I didn't see that before, I guess...?