# Providing the full path doesn't work but calling just the name of the program does, why?

Tags: bash, ruby, which

What am I missing?  I can call "rvm" from the command line but not reference the entire path that `which rvm` says I'm using.

Not that it's important, but I stay logged in as "jenkins" the entire time and these commands are executed in succession.

```
$ whoami
jenkins
```

RVM is located here

```
$ which rvm
/home/jenkins/.rvm/bin/rvm
```

This works

```
$ rvm use 1.8.7
Using /home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370
Running /home/jenkins/.rvm/hooks/after_use
```

But this doesn't work

```
$ /home/jenkins/.rvm/bin/rvm use 1.8.7
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
You need to change your terminal settings to allow shell login.
Please visit https://rvm.io/workflow/screen/ for example.
```

Yes, I have visited the link that is referenced but I don't see how it applies to me.

Comment: Try `type rvm` and see what it tells you.  It's likely that you aren't supposed to invoke `~/.rvm/bin/rvm` directly, and that `rvm` is actually something else.

Comment: Ah...just thinking out loud...So, `rvm is a function` is telling me that when I call `rvm`, it's calling the function, passing arguments if applicable, etc., but I can't "execute" the file because it's not a program, it's just the function rvm and that function is pulled into my interactive session because of the following lines in my ~/.bash_profile: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`  Makes sense now!  Thanks!

Comment: Coould you please add the result of `type rvm` and `ls -l $(which rvm)` please?

Comment: @rahmu It seems that `rvm` is a shell function defined in `~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`.  See comment above by OP.

Comment: `rvm is a function`
Then, <...>(displays content of ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm<...>
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 jenkins jenkins 1274 2012-09-14 16:28 /home/jenkins/.rvm/bin/rvm`

Answer (score 2):

`which rvm` looks for an executable called `rvm`. That executable only outputs the “RVM is not a function …” message when run.

`rvm` is probably a function, or perhaps an alias, in your shell. It has been defined in your `~/.bashrc` (or in the system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc` or in a file included from one of these). To see what the `rvm` command is, run `type rvm` or `command -v rvm`.

See also [How to use `which` on an aliased command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command)

Answer (score 0):

`rvm use` works by modifying environment variables to indicate which version of ruby should be used. This can only be done if it is run as a function. If you run it as a command, either by using the full path or not having the function defined, that can't work. This is because if run as a separate process that process gets its own copy of the environment, that copy gets modified but is immediately lost when the process exits.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added

```
#!/bin/bash --login
```

in the beginning of the script in my Hudson job.
Everything works now! :)