# Resolve nested aliases to their source commands

Tags: bash, alias

I've made several aliases for my convenience.But now I need to be helpful by sending a useful command and it is full of aliases.I've tried doing `type u` but all it returns is

`up && ap upgrade -y --show-progress && r && ap check && ap autoclean`

These are all aliases in `u`:

```
alias a='alias'
a ap='apt-get'
a r='ap autoremove -y'
a up='ap update'
```

Comment: I apologize, I am having trouble understanding your question. When you say `type u` and "These are all aliases in `u`", what is `u`? And is `up && ap upgrade -y etc......` the command you are trying to execute? If yes, then can you tell us in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: Take a look at `help unalias`.

Comment: @Celada No need to apologize, I could have explained it more.`type` command says something about something so `type u` says something about alias named `u` The problem is it returns what the command `u` does but it contains more aliases.

Comment: @Cyrus is this pernament?

Comment: @user251046: no.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-e</kbd> with a command using your aliases written (ready to run) and [Bash will expand it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shell_002dexpand_002dline-_0028M_002dC_002de_0029). <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-e</kbd> is the default binding for the `shell-expand-line` readline command.

Each time you push <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-e</kbd> Bash will expand one layer of alias, so push it repeatedly until your command is expanded as far as you need.

<sub>If your <kbd>Meta</kbd> key is not <kbd>Alt</kbd>, substitute it instead, or press <kbd>Escape</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-e</kbd></sub>.

There is also an [`alias-expand-line`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-alias_002dexpand_002dline-_0028_0029) function which is not bound by default, which only expands aliases.

Comment: You'll need to keep pressing this key combination until the line is fully expanded if you have aliases within aliases as is the case with the OP.

Comment: @JosephR. Oh thanks, I've found it out myself anyway though.

Comment: @user251046 I figured you would. This is just a caveat for any future readers.

Comment: @JosephR. to be taken with a grain of salt for recursive aliases (like `alias ls='ls --colour'`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas haha it actually makes text art.

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-e` doesn't expand only aliases. It also expands variables, arithmetic and command substitutions (and process substitutions!), though not tilde or globs, all of them on the command line, so use with care! `alias-expand-line` would be a better widget but is not bound by default. See also `Ctrl-X a` in `zsh` to expand the alias under the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071192/expand-an-alias-that-executes-another-alias-nested-alias/50141326) (probably should have posted here on Unix & Linux).

My solution was to write a bash function:

```
xtrace() {
    local eval_cmd
    printf -v eval_cmd '%q' "${@}"
    { set -x
      eval "${eval_cmd}"
    } 2>&1 | grep '^++'
    return "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
}
```

So `xtrace u` will print out something like:

```
++ apt-get update
++ apt-get upgrade -y --show-progress
++ apt-get autoremove -y
++ apt-get check
++ apt-get autoclean
```

Keep in mind that this actually executes whatever alias you pass to it, so if you don't want to execute `u`, then @MichaelHomer's solution is the better way to go. Also, because of your `&&` chain, if any one of the commands in your alias does not return 0, then execution will stop and you will only see the expanded aliases up to that point.