# How to check if vim is installed?

Tags: shell-script, command, rc

I want to know how to check whether a command is installed.

Specifically, I want to alias `vi` to `vim` on all machines where `vim` is a valid command.  And I want to keep my *rc files generic.  But some OSes don't come with `vim` installed by default.  And in others, `vi` ***is*** Vi IMproved, yet `vim` isn't a valid command.

I figured I could do this (bash style):

```
#If the version info from vi includes the phrase "Vi IMproved", then vi IS vim.
vimInfo=$(vi --version 2> /dev/null | head -n 1 | grep -Fi 'VI IMPROVED')
if [[ -z $vimInfo ]]; then
  if [[ -f $(which vim) ]]; then
    #if the value returned by 'which' is a valid directory, then vim is installed
    alias vi='vim'
  else
    #vim is not installed
    echo "Vi IMproved (vim) is not installed";
  fi
fi
```

But is there a better way?  And is the `which` command guaranteed to be present on all unix-like machines?

P.S. I have *rc files for nearly every popular shell (bash, tcsh, zsh, ksh), and I intend to apply the solution in all of them.  Therefore, the solution should not be shell-specific.  The syntax *can* be, though.

Comment: Check here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command

Comment: (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command) `type` doesn't work in tcsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `command` e.g.:

```
command -v vim
```

It is a shell built-in command. (zsh, bash, ksh, *but not* tcsh)

In *tcsh* you can use this:

```
~> sh -c 'command -v vim'
```

Comment: Is this better than using `which`?  And if so why/how?

Comment: @Sildoreth http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating this.

```
if type vim >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  alias vi=vim
fi
```

The only reason to run `vim` and `vi` is if there are systems where these are valid commands, but the installation is somehow broken or there is another program by that name.

The `type` builtin exists in all POSIX shells and most Bourne shells. In csh (and [only in csh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)), use `which`:

```
if ({ which vim }) alias vi vim >&/dev/null
```

In fish:

```
if type vim >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; alias vi=vim; end
```