# Where do aliases come from in my terminal

Tags: bash, shell, alias

Whenever I start my bash terminal on Windows (git-bash) and I run `alias` I get the following aliases:

```
$ alias
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ls='ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars'
alias ltsc='$(npm bin)/tsc'
alias lwbc='$(npm bin)/webpack'
alias node='winpty node.exe'
```

In my `.bashrc` I have only the following:

```
alias lwbc="\$(npm bin)/webpack"
alias ltsc="\$(npm bin)/tsc"
```

In my `.bash_profile` I have the following:

```
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

I don't have `.profile` file.

So where do these come from:

```
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ls='ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars'
alias node='winpty node.exe'
```

**Update:**

I've found that these aliases come from `/etc/profile.d/aliases.sh`, now how do I know where this file is triggered from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use \`which\` on an aliased command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command)

Comment: @jasonwryan, how `which` is relevant here?

Comment: try `bash -lxv -c exit 2>&1 | grep alias`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, thanks, please see my update

Comment: what i typically do is- I know the file `aliases.sh` most likely has to be called by some other file so I do a `grep -l   aliases.sh   /etc/*` then do  `grep -l  aliases.sh  /etc/*/*`  and so on till I hopefully track it down.  worst case `/etc/profile.d/aliases.sh` is hard coded in some binary or kernel in which case you would not find it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an excerpt from the documentation for bash:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`,
>   `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and
>   executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.
>   The `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to
>   inhibit this behavior.

Since you have already checked the contents of `.bashrc` and
`.bash_profile` in your home directory, it is likely for the answer to
your question to lie in file `/etc/profile`; some distributions set up
defaults for all users there, including aliases. If not, this
configuration may be in one of the other files mentioned in the above
excerpt.

Answer (score 2):

Ask bash to print a trace of the commands it runs when it starts up.

```
bash -x
```

The trace only shows the commands as they are executed, it doesn't show which file they come from. But they have to come from a file that bash is reading: first `/etc/bash.bashrc` (if enabled on your system), then `~/.bashrc`, plus any additional files sourced with the command `.` or `source` that, if used, appears in the trace.

If the aliases don't appear when you run plain `bash`, only in a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856), then they're defined in the wrong place and you should move them to `~/.bashrc`. To investigate where they're currently loaded from, run a login instance of bash with tracing on: `bash -l -x`

Comment: @Maximus The files in `/etc/profile.d` are read from `/etc/profile`, which is read by login shells.

Comment: thanks, got it. It's not easy to understand the contents of `/etc/profile` though

Answer (score 1):

I use SUSE and can tell you for this distribution those aliases are in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.
And if you use a csh or tcsh then it would be in `/etc/csh.cshrc`.
These are specific to your linux distribution, and it is recommended you do not modify them. Instead create and edit `/etc/bash.bashrc.local` as an administrator, and you will notice at the bottom of the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file it will do a `test -s /etc/bash.bashrc.local` and if the file exists it will run it.

I hate those `ls` aliases also.  I have been commenting out `alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'` for years  in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.  Just be aware that when you patch your system and do kernel updates, this `/etc/bash.bashrc` file can get overwritten, so you'll have to go back in and re-edit.

you mention you are using **bash terminal on Windows (git-bash)** so I don't know if `/etc/bash.bashrc` specifically exists for you.