# Why is `which <command>` not picking up aliases?

Tags: alias, which

I'm on OSX and if I run `python --version` in a bash shell, I get this:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

But the `which python` command appears to be pointing to version 2.7.

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python ls -al /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  admin  36 11 Apr 22:28 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python
```

I think this is because I have done `alias python=python3`: but why does `which python` not pick up the alias?

Comment: … which points out that the premise of this question is faulty, because sometimes _it does_.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10525/5132

Comment: The `type` command may be of interest to you...

Comment: @JdeBP have edited title.

Answer (score 1):

GNU which - is a utility that is used to find which executable (or alias or shell function) is executed when entered on the shell prompt.

Stolen from the which(1) man page:

The recommended way to use this utility is by adding an alias (C shell) or shell function (Bourne
       shell) for `which` like the following:

```
which () {
  (alias; declare -f) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot $@
}
export -f which
```

Put this in your `~/.bashrc` or whatever shell you use to enable this permanently.