# shell script not working in Linux Centos7 but working in cloud shell environment

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos

I am having a shell `.myenv` which is calling another shell `testenv.sh`

- `.myenv`

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env sh
  source ./testenv.sh
  ```
- `testenv.sh`

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then
    echo 'Linux detected'
    python_binaries_path='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
  elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
    echo 'MacOS detected'
    python_binaries_path='/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
  else
    echo "Cannot determine OS type: ${OSTYPE}"
    exit 1
  fi
  python_binaries='python3.7 python3 python'
  python_path=$(PATH=${python_binaries_path} which ${python_binaries} | head -n 1) || true
  echo "python_path=$python_path"
  python_major_version=$(${python_path} -c 'import platform; major, minor, patch = platform.python_version_tuple(); print(major)')

  echo "python_major_version=$python_major_version"
  echo "python_binaries_path=$python_binaries_path"
  ```

When I do `source .myenv`, it's not able to detect the `python_major_version`

```
Linux detected
python_path=alias python='python3.7'
-bash: alias: -c: not found
-bash: alias: `import platform; major, minor, patch ': invalid alias name
python_major_version=
python_binaries_path=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

When I do `sh testenv.sh`, it is able to detect the `python_major_version`

```
Linux detected
python_path=/usr/local/bin/python3.7
python_major_version=3
python_binaries_path=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Below line is creating problem and I am running these scripts on Centos7.

```
python_major_version=$(${python_path} -c 'import platform; major, minor, patch = platform.python_version_tuple(); print(major)')
```

But this script is working fine in Google cloud shell which obviously as cloud shell runs in Debian environment

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I am looking for a solution or change to a script so that it can work in both Linux and cloud shell environment.

I feel alias is causing some problem. below is my `.bashrc` file

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=
# User specific aliases and functions
alias python=python3.7
alias pip=pip3.7
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command

Comment: Eveything hinges on how you call `.myenv`, and possibly from what shell. Can you add that to your question, please

Comment: I am just doing source .myenv which call another script testenv.sh. also if I do source testenv.sh , it's not working

Comment: @Carsten S. Thanks this solution also works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let's start with the easy bit

> When I do `sh testenv.sh` [...]

That's wrong. You've written a `bash` script, and even declared it as such, so call it with `bash` not with `sh`.

2. More of the same

In the file `.myenv` you show that you have

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
source ./testenv.sh
```

so you're declaring that this is a `sh` script (not a `bash` script), but then you're using `source` to pull `testenv.sh` in to this instance of `sh`. But we've already seen that `testenv.sh` is a `bash` script, not a `sh` script. So, unless you're using `bash` to run this `sh` script it will all come miserably tumbling down at the first opportunity.

On your local system you probably have `sh` as an alias for `bash`. On your cloud system it is almost certain that `sh` is an alias for a different shell such as `dash`. This is perfectly correct and the system is trying to make sense of your incorrect code.

Please stop using `source`, and also stop mixing `sh` and `bash` interchangeably. They are (or can be) different shells with different syntax.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that `source` is a non-portable, bash alias for the standard `.` command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have accepted that but I cannot change the way they are executing this script. I did change one line as "python_path=$(PATH=${python_binaries_path} type -P ${python_binaries} | head -n 1) || true" It is working now.. is that fine to do so. Please suggest

Comment: I haven't even looked at the `python` line. The rest is so wrong it really ought to be fixed first

Comment: In production we are executing it as source .myenv only

Comment: @vikrantrana from what shell? Whatever that is, it's what is executing all your different scripts. Stop using `source`.

Comment: they are executing this in cloud shell env but for testing I have to execute them in Linux also.. I got your point. Thanks

Comment: could you please suggest also for below issue https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610875/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sqlite3