# Why does a command called by its name behave differently when it is called by full path?

Tags: bash, kill

I wanted to use `kill --verbose ...` in a bash script but I got the error `kill: -verbose: invalid signal specification`. This was weird as it worked fine in fish. My investigation has lead me to this weird behaviour:

```
$ which kill
/usr/bin/kill
$ sleep 5 & kill --verbose $!
[1] 33730
bash: kill: -verbose: invalid signal specification
... wait for sleep to finish ... 
[1]+  Done                    sleep 5
$ sleep 5 & /usr/bin/kill --verbose $!
[1] 33964
sending signal 15 to pid 33964
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 5
```

What is going on? Why does `kill` not recognise the `--verbose` flag, but `/usr/bin/kill` does, when `which kill` == `/usr/bin/kill`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`which` is misleading](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10525/86440); try `type` instead:

```
$ type kill
kill is a shell builtin
```

When you run `kill`, bash uses its built-in command, which doesn’t recognise `--verbose`. When you specify the full path, the external command `/usr/bin/kill` is run instead, and that does support `--verbose` (in your case).